# How to remove an item from array using Splice

Tags: angular

I have a variable `Data` that stores a  list of array which is rendered in the view. When the delete option of the item is selected it send data to a function where the delete function takes place. I have been able to get index of the array that i want removed from the view but how to splice it.

Comment: Show some effort of your code will be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create the following variable.

```
const index = // Assign the indexOf array over here
this.data.splice(index, 1);
```